# Delete a value from every pair in a list where the first element of the pair is in another list

Tags: list, scheme, element

This is really confusing....

Lets say we have 2 lists

```
(define abc  '((1 (1 2 3)) (2 (2 3)) (4 (1 3))))
(define keys '(1 2))

(define value 2)
```

I want to write a function that deletes the value provided,  from the second element in every pair of the first list which has the first element in the second list

```
eg. define deleteValue(abc keys value )

and result   '((1 (1  3)) (2 (3)) (4 (1 3))))
```

I have this piece of code which does smth else but maybe it is usefull

```
(define (decrement-assoc-values alist keys)
  (map (lambda (ass)
         (if (member (car ass) keys)
             (list (car ass) (- (cadr ass) 1))
             ass))
       alist))

(define abc  '((1  3) (2 3) (4  3)))
(define lst '(1 2))

(decrement-assoc-values abc  lst )
Result : '((1 2) (2 2) (4 3))
```

this decrements by 1 the second element of the pair which has the first element in the second list

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the function correctly. what is the 2 in `deleteValue(abc keys 2)` for?

Comment: Is the value we want to delete from the second part of each pair.. I made 1-2 updates in my example.. It was a little bit confusing.. My bad..

Comment: The procedure is very similar to the example you already have. Just replace `(- (cadr ass) 1)` with `(remove* value (cadr ass))`. See my answer for additional details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it.

```
(define (delete-value abc keys value)
  (map (λ (pair)
         (if(member (car pair) keys)
            (list (car pair)
                  (filter (λ(x)
                             (not(equal? x value))) 
                          (car (cdr pair))))
         pair)) 
    abc))
```